# Уменьшить размер java приложения

Tags: java, telegram-bot, зависимости

Как уменьшить размер скомпилированного java приложения включающая в себя зависимости? А именно библиотека TelegramBot'а весит 13.3 Мб. Возможно ли как либо сократить размер?

Comment: Выпилить оттуда все лишнее. Использовать более легкие форматы картинок и други ресурсов. К примеру можно не тянуть всю библиотеку TelegramBot-a а вытащить ручками оттуда только то, что нужно

Comment: Может ещё эта ссылка поможет
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309644/how-to-reduce-size-of-jar-file